# Change parameter value with iteration

Tags: python, excel, row, col

I have an Excel file, and I need to grab some data from it. When I use regular integers, everything works just fine, but now I got very stuck - how can I change row value? That's what I have for now

```
dict_keys = ['Id', 'First name', 'Age', 'Condition Name', 'BiRad', 'Relevant Modality']
dict_values = [p_id, person_name, p_age, name, br, r]
if f == 'Mass':   
    #concatvals accepts (row, col, width, start, stop)
    shape = concatvals(row, 14, 5, 14, 19) #if row = 0
    margin = concatvals(row, 14, 5, 14, 19) #here row should be 1
    density = concatvals(row, 14, 5, 14, 19) # and here 2 - how to achieve that?
    dict_keys += ['Relevant Finding','Shape', 'Margin', 'Density']
    dict_values += [f, shape, margin, density]
```

And that's what I tried:

```
if f == 'Mass':
    params = [shape, margin, density]
    loc = (row, 14, 5, 14, 19)
    for param in params:
        params[i] = concatvals(loc)
        loc[0] +=1
```

But didn't succeed to go further. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You could make your example simpler to understand by leaving out the `f = 'Mass'` part (eta: and the test `if f == 'Mass'` which does nothing), even if you're going to use it later on.

Comment: It looks like you just need a loop `for row in range(3):` - does this make sense?

Comment: It doesn't work out, and also I have various ranges/params. I need to have it more generic.

Comment: Could you check your identation?

Comment: Is your indentation correct? In the example of what you tried, `params[i] = concatvals(loc)` needs to be indented to fall within the `for` loop. Same with `loc[0] += 1`.

Comment: Indirectly writing to variables like that is difficult to do in Python; much more easily achieved with a `dict` - or just an array, as in the answer I've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Make `row` a loop parameter, and save the calculated values in an array:

```
dict_keys = ['Id', 'First name', 'Age', 'Condition Name', 'BiRad', 'Relevant Modality']
dict_values = [p_id, person_name, p_age, name, br, r]

#concatvals accepts (row, col, width, start, stop)
vals = []
for row in range(3):
    vals += concatvals(row, 14, 5, 14, 19)
dict_keys += ['Relevant Finding','Shape', 'Margin', 'Density']
dict_values += [f]
dict_values += vals
```

Comment: Its not what he wants, you even asked that yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit confusion you use `dict__` for things which are not a dict, but a list... If I understand what you want I would arrive at this:

```
params = {'Mass': ['shape', 'margin', 'density'],
          'Next': ['some', 'other', 'list']}
if f == 'Mass':
    loc = (row, 14, 5, 14, 19)
    result = [f]
    for param in params[f]:
        result.append(concatvals(loc))
        loc[0] +=1
    dict_keys += ['Relevant Finding','Shape', 'Margin', 'Density']
    dict_values += result
elif f == 'Next':
    ... etc ...
```

Comment: I also have a function to create a dict from those two lists. That's not so important for now, but I'm checking out your solution and appreciate your help.

Comment: Its a bit since people here try to undersatnd your code to help you ;) so the more intuitive it is... But does this help?

Comment: Can you please explain, why did you put params outside? I have these params for this "if" statement and I have other for "elif".

Comment: Sorry for being confusing and maybe messy.

Comment: Did that because it did not seem to change in the code you posted :) so then it would be redundant to define them again every loop. Edited my answer - I would define the parameters outside in a dictionary like this. then you can use them in each of your if`s.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'shape' referenced before assignment - that's what I have all time long.

Comment: Then I guess params should be strings. See my new update.

Comment: Thanks, but still I can't apply updated params to create a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147940/discussion-between-alice-jarmusch-and-roelant).